# Why does Interface Builder keep screwing up my custom view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I only started using IB recently, so maybe this has been an ongoing problem for longer than I think, but frequently when Xcode restarts, any storyboard using one of my custom views will have the incorrect frame set. See the below screenshot.

[image]

Corrected, it looks like this:

[image]

The constraints are all set correctly. What could possibly make it do this? Do I have to do something special for IB when overriding `intrinsicContentSize`?

Edit: Added bug report.
28685181 Interface Builder sets view frame to 1000x1000 when Xcode is opened.

Comment: Usually you can go to the "resolve autolayout issues" button in the lower right corner of the IB canvas and then choose "update frames" and it fixes that. Or are you saying that you fixed the frames, and they're reset back to those strange values when you open it again?

Comment: Yeah, it keeps going back to the strange values even if I haven't changed the file since fixing it.

Comment: Does it switch devices? I'm designing an iPad only app (yes I specified it in the project setup) and it keeps switching to iPhone whenever I open interface builder after a reboot.

Comment: No, I think it's some bug with the new view default of 1000x1000 in IB. I've also noticed that it is happening to views that override the instrinsicContentSize property.

Comment: When you select controller on Storyboard, in right corner go to attribute inspector(middle one) there is size metrics they have given. Select iPad if not selected previously and try close and open Xcode.